# Drupal 7, managing multisites content in one admin panel

Tags: drupal

I have an awkward question, it is possible to use one admin panel for multisite drupal instalation?

For example: 
I have one drupal installation, and 5 sites running on it, so I want to create or modify nodes, blocks, etc. in one place. all sites are similar in structure

I never done multisites before, so if you have any ideas, I will love to hear it

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is impossible.

Multisites are completelly different sites, using different databases, but sharing the source code. Then you can't share content or configuration.

If you want to create sites for diferent domains, but sharing users, contents and configurations, you should use the [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) approach instead of multisites.

Regards

Comment: Thanks, my search finish on a same module)